# check for repeated characters/letter in a string

Tags: python, character

hi i want to check if a string from user input has two repeated characters/letters in a string next to eachother.. i have a simple code to check if the first letter and second letter in the string are the same.

```
def two_same():
    d = []
    while len(d) <= 1:
        d = input("enter the same letter twice:")
    if d[0] == d[1]:
        return print(d[0])
two_same()
```

but how would i check all the characters in the string and for a repeated letter from a user input.

Comment: All you have to do is keep track of the last char and compare it to the current in a loop, `return print(d[0])` is also invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments already mentioned you should use a for loop:

```
def two_same(string)
   for i in range(len(string)-1):
      if string[i] == string[i+1]:
         return True
   return False

result = ""
while not two_same(result):
   result = input("enter the same letter twice:")
print(result)
```

Comment: yea but i need to take a user input so i need to repeat the user input until they give me a string that has two characters repeated

Comment: but this function takes a string as an argument, and doesn't ask the user for the input

Comment: Therefore I added the while loop below the function, which repeatedly applies this function to a user input.

Answer (score 0):

Another method that works is to use the repeating character syntax to check if a string contains the same character.  Here is a snippet from a PyUnit test that illustrates doing this with several different strings which all contain some number of commas.

```
    # simple test
    test_string = ","

    self.assertTrue(test_string.strip() == "," * len(test_string.strip()),
                    "Simple test failed")

    # Slightly more complex test by adding spaces before and after
    test_string = " ,,,,, "

    self.assertTrue(test_string.strip() == "," * len(test_string.strip()),
                    "Slightly more complex test failed")

    # Add a different character other than the character we're checking for
    test_string = " ,,,,,,,,,a "

    self.assertFalse(test_string.strip() == "," * len(test_string.strip()),
                     "Test failed, expected comparison to be false")

    # Add a space in the middle
    test_string = " ,,,,, ,,,, "

    self.assertFalse(test_string.strip() == "," * len(test_string.strip()),
                     "Test failed, expected embedded spaces comparison to be false")

    # To address embedded spaces, we could fix the test_string 
    # and remove all spaces and then run the comparison again
    fixed_test_string = "".join(test_string.split())
    print("Fixed string contents: {}".format(fixed_test_string))
    self.assertTrue(fixed_test_string.strip() == "," * len(fixed_test_string.strip()),
                    "Test failed, expected fixed_test_string comparison to be True")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set's feature of unique elements:
if len(string_to_check) == len(set([char for char in string_to_check]))

This way all repeated characters will be counted as one (for each type of character) in the set. Comparing length of string and set, it is possible fo get number of repeated characters

Comment: Two repeated characters **next to eachother**. Your code produces same output for strings "aba" and "aab".